# Tkinter Open New Frame Without A Button Press

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I have a multi-frame Tkinter program running and am in a situation where I need a new frame to open without a button press.

If I were to have a button it would be coded like this:

```
button = tk.Button(self, text="New Window",
                   command=lambda: controller.show_frame("NewWindow"))
```

Is there a way I can make a new window open after a `time.sleep(60)` command? This is what I have tried:

```
def on_button(self):
     if LogIn in Data:
            time.sleep(5)
            print("Welcome")
            root.after(6, controller.show_frame("HomePage")) 
        else:
            print("please register")
```

Various Data and coding goes after the defining. If the condition is true it 'Logs In' This is when I want it to show the new frame

Root gives the error of: NameError: name 'root' is not defined

Controller.after(etc) gives : NameError: name 'controller' is not defined

Despite controller being used frequently without issue throughout the rest of the program

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the `after` callback See: [Alarm handlers and other non-event callbacks](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm)

> after(delay_ms, callback=None, *args) [#]
>   Registers an alarm callback that is called after a given time.

```
root.after(60000, new_window_func, args)
```

Comment: Don't call `button.after`, since the OP says they don't want a button. Instead, use `root` or `controller` (assuming `controller` is a widget). Also, I suggest giving an example based on the code in the question (eg: `root.after(60000, controller.show_frame, "NewWindow")`)

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley -- adjusted the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tested and updated my original question as there seems to be a fault with this method @BryanOakley All your help is greatly appreciated